# React native & MobX: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject [...]. But 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' doesn't exist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, observers, state-management

So my vscode keeps on giving me this error when I tried to implement mobx observer into react native.

```
Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.
```

I believe that I have followed every instruction in the website below.

https://jamesmargrove.medium.com/setting-up-a-typescript-react-native-project-with-decorators-93eb8a8ffa9

Also I can't find the `tsconfig` or `jsconfig` anywhere in my project. Please help

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a `jsconfig.json` file in the root of the project with the following contents:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh So I have to create it myself

Comment: That's right, it will also only remove the warning in VS Code. The functionality to compile decorators is added with the babel plugin mentioned in the tutorial you linked.